# jQuery Simplemodal destroying Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, simplemodal

I am using jQuery Simplemodal v 1.4.4 to show a modal dialog containing an input field which uses jQuery Autocomplete.

The autocomplete works normally the first time simplemodal is invoked, but the binding gets destroyed when simplemodal closes.

I know this can be avoided using Simplemodal onOpen/onClose callbacks, but that solution is cumbersome in my case as I'm managing several different modal dialogs dynamically:

```
if ($(edit_container).hasClass('modal')) {                          
$(edit_container).modal();                          
}
```

This means I would have to check for various autocomplete fields inside simplemodal callbacks, which really isn't an elegant solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Admittedly not familiar with this plugin but a quick look at the close function reveals that the modal is `remove()`ed (destroyed) when the modal is closed. How are you implementing autocomplete?